# Spark Keeping at max 10 duplicates in a dataset

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, duplicates

I have been experimenting with a large dataset with Spark. One of the fundamental problems with my data is that it has duplicates, and I want to remove them. But my removal case is a bit different as I would like to keep at max 10 duplicates in my data and remove everything else.

I experimented with the `.dropDuplicates()` function only to find out that it eliminates all the duplicates from the dataset. Any help or pointers are appreciated here.

Comment: you can use a window function to remove duplicate with keep number of duplicate Rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below code.

```
scala> val df = Seq(("Srinivas",1),("Ravi",2),("Srinivas",1),("Srinivas",1),("Kumar",3),("Srinivas",1),("Srinivas",1),("Srinivas",1),("Srinivas",1)).toDF("name","age")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int]

scala> df.orderBy($"name").show(false) // 7 duplicate names.
+--------+---+
|name    |age|
+--------+---+
|Kumar   |3  |
|Ravi    |2  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
+--------+---+


scala> val keepOnly = 4
keepOnly: Int = 4

scala> val duplicates = df.withColumn("rowid",row_number().over(Window.partitionBy($"name",$"age").orderBy($"name",$"age"))).withColumn("rowid",when($"rowid" > keepOnly,lit(1)).otherwise($"rowid"))
duplicates: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string, age: int ... 1 more field]

scala> duplicates.show(false)
+--------+---+-----+
|name    |age|rowid|
+--------+---+-----+
|Srinivas|1  |1    |
|Srinivas|1  |2    |
|Srinivas|1  |3    |
|Srinivas|1  |4    |
|Srinivas|1  |1    |
|Srinivas|1  |1    |
|Srinivas|1  |1    |
|Kumar   |3  |1    |
|Ravi    |2  |1    |
+--------+---+-----+


scala> duplicates.drop
drop   dropDuplicates

scala> duplicates.dropDuplicates.drop("rowid").show(false)
+--------+---+
|name    |age|
+--------+---+
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Srinivas|1  |
|Kumar   |3  |
|Ravi    |2  |
+--------+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`Window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Window.html) to partition the data by all columns. Each partition will contain all the rows that are the same  (i.e., they are duplicates).

We can then use [`row_number()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#row_number--) to number the rows within each partition and remove the ones that are abouve the threshold. This can be done as follows (in Scala):

```scala
val maxDuplicate = 10

// partiton over all columns, ordering by one of them
val w = Window.partitionBy(df.columns.head, df.columns.tail: _*).orderBy(df.columns.head)

df.withColumn("rowNum", row_number().over(w))
  .filter($"rowNum" <= maxDuplicate)
  .drop("rowNum")
```